# Referring a former colleague

Tags: referral

I was recently approached by a person from my past job asking me if I can refer her for a position in my current company. I did referred and She was able to get a job. After interview she did not even care to let me know that she finished interview and got the offer. I find it very disappointing and feel used. Is it too much to expect this? I want to confront her about this situation.

Comment: Did you ask them to let you know when they finished their interview and receive an offer?

Comment: What is the outcome you would like get? Just confronting her without an idea of what you want the end result to be will probably not help much.

Comment: "About that job - how did it go?"

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm not sure confronting (as I understand it) is the best way here. Maybe ask a question if you happen to run into them, or leave it - is my take (expanded that into an answer actually).

Comment: @matt I don’t thought of any outcome as such. Just wanted to get it out of my chest and move on. Isn’t a basic thing to do to let the person know about the job offer?

Comment: This is nothing to do with the workplace, and just about your personal interactions with this person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I agree with you that this is unprofessional, but what do you expect to achieve by "confronting" them?

- An apology? What good is that?
- Guilt trip? What good is that?
- Not to have this repeated in future? What guarantee do/will you have?

Basically, let go and move on. If you come across them in the cafeteria or the watercooler, just say hi and mention that you were wondering about the status as you did not get to hear anything on that (do not confront them, use a neutral tone/pitch). If they missed to update you (for whatever reason), they'll tell you that. If they wanted to avoid you (again, for whatever reason), they'll make up excuses. Either way, you get what you *need* to know. Leave it at that, do not stretch it further.